# Filtering IEnumerable by collection (Linq)

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filter an IEnumerable object by a specific property of whatever object it is collecting. I want the option to filter by one or more property value **but** how many values (and what values) to filter by is only known at runtime.

Ok, so to give an example, the collected objects could be the following struct:

```
public struct Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Profession{ get; set; }
}
```

This struct could then be used by the following list, which I have populated with some arbitrary values:

```
List<Person> people= new List<Person>;
people.Add(new Person(){Name = "Mickey", Profession="Tinker"};
people.Add(new Person(){Name = "Donald", Profession="Tailor"};
people.Add(new Person(){Name = "Goofy", Profession="Soldier"};
people.Add(new Person(){Name = "Pluto", Profession="Spy"};
```

This is then put into an IEnumerable (all of them are transferred to it first)

```
var wantedPeople = from n in this.people select n;
```

So say a user was only interested in the "Tailor" and "Spy" professions, and via some sort of gui trickery the following collection was created:

```
List<string> wantedProfessions = new List<string>();
wantedProfessions.Add("Tailor");
wantedProfessions.Add("Spy");
```

Now what Linq statement can I use to filer my wantedPeople so it only includes the tailor and spy entries?
I know I could use a where clause but I don't know how to tailor it to get what I want (and doing the following is **not what I want** as it only works with the wantedProfessions collection above (e.g. this collection will change at runtime):

```
wantedPeople = from n in wantedPeople
              where n.Profession == wantedProffessions[0] || n.Profession == wantedProffessions[1]
              select n;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to check any wanted profession from given list:

```
wantedPeople = from n in wantedPeople
               where wantedProffessions.Contains(n.Profession)
               select n;
```

---

Or you can build query with lambda syntax by applying filters one by one:

```
var query = people.AsEnumerable();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    query = query.Where(p => p.Name == name);

if (wantedProfessions.Any())
    query = query.Where(p => wantedProfessions.Contains(p.Profession));
```

---

If you wanted to create more complex filters, like some name, and several professions, you can use [Specification pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf). Specification can be defined by this simple interface:

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
   bool Satisfied(T entity);
}
```

It just checks whether given entity (person) satisfies specification. Specification also look very simple:

```
public class PersonNameSpecification : ISpecification<Person>
{
    private string _name;
    public PersonNameSpecification(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public bool Satisfied(Person person)
    {
        return person.Name == _name;
    }
}
```

Profession specification:

```
public class PersonProfessionSpecification : ISpecification<Person>
{
    private string[] _professions;
    public PersonProfessionSpecification(params string[] professions)
    {
        _professions = professions;
    }
    public bool Satisfied(Person person)
    {
        return _professions.Contains(person.Profession);
    }
}
```

You can create specifications which implement boolean logic, like OrSpecification or AndSpecification:

```
public class AndSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>
{
    private ISpecification<T> _specA;
    private ISpecification<T> _specB;
    public AndSpecification(ISpecification<T> specA, ISpecification<T> specB)
    {
        _specA = specA;
        _specB = specB;
    }
    public bool Satisfied(T entity)
    {
        return _specA.Satisfied(entity) && _specB.Satisfied(entity);
    }
}

public static class SpecificationExtensions
{
    public static ISpecification<T> And<T>(
       this ISpecification<T> specA, ISpecification<T> specB)
    {
        return new AndSpecification<T>(specA, specB);
    }
}
```

Now you can create complex specification which describes people you want to get:

```
var professionSpec = new PersonProfessionSpecification("Tailor", "Spy");
var nameSpec = new PersonNameSpecification("Pluto");
var spec = professionSpec.And(nameSpec);
```

And get required people:

```
var result = people.Where(spec.Satisfied);
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey and aplogies for the long delay.

Answer (score 0):

Sergey B's Solution is the correct one for your example.

Assuming that you weren't using a collection that had the Contains() method, you could also do the following:

```
var wantedPeople = from n in people
                   from p in wantedProffessions
                   where n.Profession.Equals(p)
                   select n;
```

Comment: Actually I would go with `join` in that case - it creates lookup internally which is more efficient than enumerating both collections O(n*m)